# how to split only filename with extension by using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, filenames

I am developing application, i have one url like `http://edvancepreschoolsadminpanel.com/viverobranch/files/newsletter/113605sample.jpg`. I am going to save this url in Database, now I am getting filename with extension like 113605sample.jpg by using this query

```
SELECT 
    A1.id,
    A1.year,
    A1.month,
    A1.title,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(A1.file,'\\/',-1) AS file,
    A1.class,
    A2.classname,
    A1.time 
FROM 
    p_news_letters A1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN class A2 ON A1.class = A2.classid 
    where A1.School_Id=1 and A1.Status=1 and ".$where." limit $offset,$rows";
```

For example `113605sample.jpg` is my filename but the number is (before `filename` it is `113605`) a random number generated by using php because of unique purpose. My requirement is i want to display only filename with extension  like (sample.jpg) 
already i am using this method  `SUBSTRING_INDEX(A1.file,'\\/',-1)` to retrieve only (113605sample.jpg) from whole url but i don't know how to split as my requirement could you please help me to resolve this issues

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @SagarJoon i am using 1and1 online database

Comment: What's 1and1 online database?

Comment: The best (for speed) idea would be to split it programmatically and write in a separate field. And don't have trouble with parsing URL in query

Comment: yeah,`what's 1 and 1 online database` ?

Comment: @sqluser 1and1 is my online server i am using online server database Mysql